# Normal vector of a given vector

Tags: vectors

Say that I have the vector $\mathbf{v}=(1,-2,1)$ and I want to find a normal vector to $\mathbf{v}$.

$\mathbf{a}=(1,1,1)$ and any scalar multiple of it is normal to $\mathbf{n}$ since $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$.

But $\mathbf{b}=(-3,1,5)$ and any scalar multiple of it is also a normal vector to $\mathbf{v}$ since $\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$.

I hoped that since both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are normal to $\mathbf{v}$, then $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ should be parallel but this not the case since they are not scalar multiple of each other.

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: There is a "plane" of vectors normal to $\bf v$. Any two vectors in this plane will be normal to $\bf v$, but not necessarily parallel to each other.

Comment: So are you saying that both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ would lie in the same plane?

Comment: They would determine the plane mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In two dimensions, if two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are both normal to a third vector $\mathbf{v}$, you can state that one of the two normal vectors is a scalar multiple of the other $\mathbf{a} = \lambda \mathbf{b}$. The normal vectors are either parallel or antiparallel.

However, in three dimensions, this need not be the case. An entire plane is defined by the set of vectors normal to a given vector $\mathbf{v}$. The only relationship you can state with certainty is that $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$, i.e. the cross-product of the two normal vectors is parallel or antiparallel to the original vector. Note that $\lambda$ can be zero, which occurs when $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are either parallel or antiparallel themselves (like in the 2-D analogue).

Answer (score 0):

In the drawing below (which I just found online), the vector called "normal vector" is your vector $v$. You want to find other vectors that are normal to $v$, but there are an infinite number of such vectors. Indeed, all vectors normal to $v$ lie in a plane, as shown in the drawing. Your vectors $a$ and $b$ will be in the plane, but they will not necessarily be parallel.

[image: a plane normal to a vector]