# Relation between determinants and co planar vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have the following question here:

> Let $$\vec{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3),\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3),\vec{w}=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$$
> be $3$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Define a matrix whose rows are these three vectors:
> $$\begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3\\ 
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> a) Show that $$\det(A)=\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w})$$

This proof was trivial. Simply compute $\vec{v} \times \vec{w} = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3\\ 
\end{vmatrix}$ and dot the result with $\vec{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$. Compute the determinant (I used cofactor expansion) and you'll get both sides to match.

> b) Suppose that $\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are not colinear. Show that $\vec{v} \times \vec{w}$ is normal to the plane given by $\text{Span}\{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$.

Since $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are not collinear, this implies any vecotor can be written as the span of the two vectors. Let $\vec{u}=\alpha\vec{v}+\beta\vec{w}$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are real numbers. If $\vec{u}$ is normal to $\vec{v} \times \vec{w}$ then $\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})$ implies:

$\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})$

$(\alpha\vec{v}+\beta\vec{w})\cdot(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})$

$(\alpha\vec{v})\cdot(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})+(\beta\vec{w})\cdot(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})=0$

It's $0$ since two of the rows are the same so the determinant (Since the is the same as part a) evaluates to $0$ as well.

> c) Use parts (a) and (b) to argue that $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ all lie on the same plane if and only if $\det(A)=0$.

I can do this geometrically quite easily since this is just the volume of the parallelipiped spanned by the three vectors $\vec{u}$,$\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$.

Is there a way way to argue this algebraically though? I keep reading various links about how this relates to the normal vector but I can't seem to put it together.

The most common answer I see is:

"If $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are coplanar, their triple product $\mathbf{u} \cdot (\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w})$ is $0$ since $\mathbf{u}$ must be perpendicular to $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w}$."

Why though? I feel silly asking this but why does $\vec{u}$ have the be orthogonal to $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$? I feel like I'm missing a very simple and obvious step here.

Can someone draw out some kind of visual for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could also follow by the point-normal definition of a plane: $\mathbf{\vec{n}}\cdot \vec{x} = 0$.

Given two points $x_1,x_2 \in \mathcal{P}$ then the vector $\vec{x} = \mathbf{x_2} - \mathbf{x_1 }\in \mathcal{P}$, and the normal has the property that is perpendicular to all vectors in $\mathcal{P}$:

If $\vec{x} \in \mathcal{P}$ (the plane), then $\mathbf{\vec{n}}\cdot \vec{x} = 0$.

The normal of the plane $\mathcal{P}_{\vec{v},\vec{w}}$ made by noncolinear vectors $\vec{v},\vec{w}$ is $\mathbf{\vec{n}} = \vec{v} \times \vec{w}\not= \vec{0}$, and if $\vec{u} \in \mathcal{P}_{\vec{v},\vec{w}}$ then $\det(A)=(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})\cdot \vec{u}= \mathbf{\vec{n}}\cdot \vec{u} =0$.

If $\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are colinear then $\mathbf{\vec{n}}=\vec{0}$ and certainly $\vec{0}\cdot\vec{u} =0$.

There's an image of the normal vector to a plane in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313178/normal-vector-of-a-given-vector).

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FutureMathperson if you’re further interested, the algebra behind your geometric reasoning, the proof of why the volume of the parallelepiped is related to the scalar triple product might provide similar insight